# MariaDb: Create a nested json object query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'd like to generate an array of json objects in MySql select query.

:: Update ::

Here is a [db structure](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37ae9b/1) for which i'd like to return the result as below format.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shops` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The expected JSON output would be:

```
{
    "products": {
        "name": "lorium"
    },
    "shop": {
        "name": "ipsum"
    }
}
```

I have searched for the same but can not get the result which is related to my topic so is it possible in mysql to create a query for rendering the above result ?

MySql version: 5.5.5

MariaDb Version: 10.3.22

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! You will need to provide the structure of your table as formatted text (use `SHOW CREATE TABLE foo\G` from your `mysql` client! Even better would be a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=2d455deb74e5cdd766602e5c5ea09767) with some sample data - but be sure to post the table structures and data here also! Furthermore, please **always, always** tag your question with your server version - this can critically affect any answer!

Comment: Thank you sir for your concern, pls review my updated question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that MySQL 5.5 doesn't have any JSON functionality. I would **strongly** advise you to upgrade to version 8 of MySQL - Oracle/MySQL have added a shedload of **really really useful** functionality since 5.5 (CHECK constraints, Common Table Expressions, Window functions, JSON). You really are missing out by using 5.5! MySQL 8 is now at version 20, time enough for any (ahem...) issues with the new functionality to have been (largely) ironed out!  Extended support for 5.5 ended on [2018-12-31](https://www.fromdual.com/support-for-mysql-from-oracle) That's year and a half ago!

Comment: From your fiddle, am I to understand that you want procduct 1 with shop 1, product 2 with shop 2 and so on?

Comment: Thanks a ton sir for super fast response. So firstly let me upgrade mine MySql version.

From your fiddle, am I to understand that you want procduct 1 with shop 1, product 2 with shop 2 and so on? : yes right sir.